# From anyObject to array of coordinates

Tags: swift, parsing, coordinates, anyobject

New to Swift and json

I want to extract lng,lat from anyObject elements.
Here a part of my code to extract from json file:

```
for (key,value) in geoFeature! as [String: AnyObject]  {print("key=",key, ptvir, value)}
let geoCoords = geoFeature?["coordinates"] as AnyObject
```

Resulting to :

```
Printing description of geoCoords:
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 11 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.596408
      - 1 : 45.453657
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.595466
      - 1 : 45.451156
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.59532
      - 1 : 45.450786
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.596114
      - 1 : 45.450639
    ▿ 4 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.596616
      - 1 : 45.450549
    ▿ 5 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.596746
      - 1 : 45.450911
    ▿ 6 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.596867
      - 1 : 45.451248
    ▿ 7 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.59716
      - 1 : 45.452082
    ▿ 8 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.597514
      - 1 : 45.45307
    ▿ 9 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.597638
      - 1 : 45.453437
    ▿ 10 : 2 elements
      - 0 : -73.596408
      - 1 : 45.453657
```

From here, I did not find the code to create an array of coordinates

Comment: It's very difficult to read, can you please print it in JSON format? https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Ipm.png

Comment: Great question, but its a bit hard to read your code. Could you reformat and provide the code around it for context? It's hard to see how the above could produce that output. For example the var `ptvir` doesn't seem to relate to anything and the `print` statement has an equal sign which doesn't appear in the output shown.

Answer (score 0):

**More details:**

From a json file like this part:

{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "MtlAires2016Bref",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ADIDU": "24661006" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -73.596408, 45.453657 ], [ -73.595466, 45.451156 ], [ -73.59532, 45.450786 ], [ -73.596114, 45.450639 ], [ -73.596616, 45.450549 ], [ -73.596746, 45.450911 ], [ -73.596867, 45.451248 ], [ -73.59716, 45.452082 ], [ -73.597514, 45.45307 ], [ -73.597638, 45.453437 ], [ -73.596408, 45.453657 ] ] ] } }
]
}

**My code extract properties for each Feature**

The problem is to extract all the polygon coordinates with the result of these 2 lines of code:

for (key,value) in geoFeature! as [String: AnyObject]  {print("key=",key, ";", value)}
let geoCoords = geoFeature?["coordinates"] as AnyObject
print("geoCoords=", geoCoords as Any)

result of this print:

geoCoords= (
(
(
"-73.596408",
"45.453657"
),
(
"-73.595466",
"45.451156"
),
(
"-73.59532",
"45.450786"
),
(
"-73.596114",
"45.450639"
),
(
"-73.596616",
"45.450549"
),
(
"-73.596746",
"45.450911"
),
(
"-73.596867",
"45.451248"
),
(
"-73.59716",
"45.452082"
),
(
"-73.597514",
"45.45307"
),
(
"-73.597638",
"45.453437"
),
(
"-73.596408",
"45.453657"
)
)
)

I did not find how to iterate in geoCoords and append coordinates to an array.

Next line give me the same listing; not array

for element in geoCoords as! Array {
//print("elem=",element)}

but if I ask for the type of the variable like this

String(describing: type(of: coordsData))

it's = Array

the next line give an empty array

let tblC = coordsData as [CLLocationCoordinate2D]

Answer (score 0):

Please learn to read JSON. It's pretty easy. There are only two collection types, array (`[]`) and dictionary (`{}`). So the value for key `coordinates` is a nested array of Double (`[[[Double]]]`).

It's impossible to cast a double array to `CLLocationCoordinate2D` because the type is not related.

And the unspecified JSON type is `Any`, never `AnyObject`

```
if let geoCoords = geoFeature["coordinates"] as? [[[Double]]] {
    for outerCoords in geoCoords {
       for innerCoords in outerCoords {
           print(innerCoords)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll do. Thank you so munch. Solution so simple! Yesterday I have find a solution with SwifttJSON. But it's very slow for 3000 polygons. The solution here is a lot faster.